# Sed command not replacing with multiline from file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace a bloc in a file (file1) from another one coming from a second file (file2).
File2 contains multiline, let's say:

```
Print 1
Print 2
```

I'm using this command:

```
file2="$(cat file2)"
sed -i "/Do_something/,/^}/c\
 echo ${file2} " ${file1}
```

The good thing is that it works but it replaces it in a single line.
How can I replace with multiline?
I tried to put directly the variable but It doesn't work, it works only with 'echo'.
Also if I add double quotes, it's doesn"t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to read `file2` in a shell variable. Just get it done in `sed` using `r file` command:

```sh
sed -e '/Do_something/,/^}/{/^}/!d; r file2' -e 'd;}' "$file1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/Do_something/{:a;N;/^}/M!ba;r file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

Replace the lines between one containing `Do_something` and another beginning `}` with the contents of file2.

N.B. The replacement will only take place if both matches are made, otherwise the default action will be leave the file untouched i.e. the `N` command will reach end-of-file and print the contents of the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box you could do (untested since you didn't provide sample input/output we could test with):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0; next }
    /Do_something/ { f=1 }
    f && /^}/ { $0=new; f=0 }
    !f
' file2 file1
```

That above assumes that if you have `Do_something` in the input then you will also have a subsequent `}` since nothing in your question suggests otherwise.

If you want to replace the contents of `file1` with the output of that command then just add `> tmp && mv tmp file1` to the end of the command.